# How to export Bigtree file/folder tree structure to an image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, directory-structure

I am currently using bigtree (https://github.com/kayjan/bigtree) to produce a file/folder tree structure from a list of file paths. I can output this tree structure in the console and it looks great.

```
from bigtree import list_to_tree, print_tree

path_list = ['\\Tuflow\\Runs\\Brooyar_~e1~_~e2~_~e3~_~s1~_002.tcf', '\\Tuflow\\model\\gis\\Projection.SHP', '\\Tuflow\\Runs\\Brooyar_001.TEF', '\\Tuflow\\model\\Brooyar_001.TGC', '\\Tuflow\\model\\Brooyar_001.TBC', '\\Tuflow\\bc_dbase\\bc_dbase_Brooyar_002.CSV', '\\Tuflow\\model\\Brooyar_001.TMF', '\\Tuflow\\model\\gis\\2d_po_Brooyar_001_L.SHP', '\\Tuflow\\model\\gis\\2d_loc_Brooyar_001_L.SHP', '\\Tuflow\\model\\gis\\2d_code_Brooyar_001_R.SHP', '\\Tuflow\\model\\DEM\\Gympie_2009_1m.ASC', '\\Tuflow\\model\\gis\\2d_zsh_elevation_adjust_001_L.SHP', '\\Tuflow\\model\\gis\\2d_mat_Brooyar_001_R.SHP', '\\Tuflow\\model\\gis\\2d_mat_Brooyar_001_R.SHP']
root = list_to_tree(path_list, sep='\\')
print_tree(root)
```

Screenshot of output:

[image]

I would then like to save this tree structure as an image to keep on file or share with others. As far as I can tell there isn't a native way to accomplish this.

The best I have come up with so far is to pull out each individual line as a string as it is created and add them to a PILLOW image. This can be a bit messy though as PILLOW doesn't seem to like the text formatting used in bigtree.

[image]

Is there a better way I can do this with bigtree outputs?

Is there a way I can make the PILLOW output image handle the output better?

Is there an alternative to bigtree that can do what I am looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: This is implemented in `bigtree` v0.6.6, thanks for your support!

Do perform a `pip install --upgrade 'bigtree[image]'` to get the updated version.

```
from bigtree import tree_to_pillow

pillow_image = tree_to_pillow(root)
pillow_image.save("tree.jpg")
```

This will result in the output

[image: Tree Image]

You can customize further with the font (family, colour, size), background colour and more - read more about it [here](https://bigtree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigtree/tree/export.html#bigtree.tree.export.tree_to_pillow).

Comment: That was a quick update! 
It looks like I was doing a similar thing, but manually, and less elegantly. After looking at your implementation it seems like mine was looking all weird because of how I was using my font choice. It's also great to have a simple in-built function for it now.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this function will help to reproduce the same output using pillow

**Example:**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os

def export_tree(root_dir, image_file):
    # create a new image and a drawing object
    img = Image.new('RGB', (800, 600), color=(255, 255, 255))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    # set the font and text color
    # font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 12)
    font = ImageFont.load_default()

    text_color = (0, 0, 0)

    # starting position for the tree
    x, y = 20, 20

    # traverse the directory tree and draw the tree on the image
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        # draw the current directory
        draw.text((x, y), os.path.basename(root), font=font, fill=text_color)
        y += 20

        # draw the subdirectories
        for d in dirs:
            draw.text((x + 20, y), d, font=font, fill=text_color)
            y += 20

        # draw the files
        for f in files:
            draw.text((x + 40, y), f, font=font, fill=text_color)
            y += 20

    # save the image
    img.save(image_file, "PNG")

export_tree("/tmp", "tree.png")
```